# If you satisfy Australia's points-based system, do you automatically get a residency visa?

Tags: working-visas, australia

Australia has a points-based system for migration where people are assessed based on the number of points they get. According to an online calculator I have 80 points and my profession is also on the list of qualified professions (software engineer). Does this mean I can automatically receive a residency visa without finding a job in advance? How does the system work?

Comment: That certainly seems to match what is on the [189 page](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/189-): no employer, permanent residency, qualified profession, etc. You fill out the forms, which include getting your degree and experience vetted, and then you may be invited to actually apply. It's similar to Canada's express entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can apply and receive the residency visa without ever setting foot in Australia or getting a job offer.  However, "automatically" is a bit optimistic: the visa application is quite a bit of work and while waiting times vary widely, it can easily take several years before you get a response.